# given heart rate data over 1year with 1Hz time res, what can we learn?

Tags: heart-rate, quantified-self

I've been wearing my fitbit charge2 for a bit over a year, of course with small pauses for charging etc.
The heart rate is measured with a 1Hz frequency and a resolution of 1.

Now fitbit determines what it thinks of as a resting heart rate and some approximation of my vo2 max.

My question is: By any means of calculus, what else can we learn from this data?
Are there any measures of interest that I can extract from these values?
Is there any software out there to do this?
I am not afraid of doing the matlab/python code myself or sharing my data.